# Problems using images in Java

Tags: java, swing, file, file-io, filepath

I'm getting weird path problems even after I've checked them, any clue whats up with this? I checked my error online and apparently its  path problem, even though I check the path just before...

```
java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource("/resources/image.gif");
    if (imgURL != null) {
        System.out.println("Working!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't find file: " + "/resources/image.gif");
    }

    JButton submitButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/image.gif")));
```

Output is:

```
Working!!
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:205)
at javaapplication17.JavaApplication17.initUI(JavaApplication17.java:38)
at javaapplication17.JavaApplication17.<init>(JavaApplication17.java:22)
at javaapplication17.JavaApplication17$1.run(JavaApplication17.java:53)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the leading `/`, in the path, while using the `ClassLoader` instance. It is required only when you do `getResource()` on `Class` instance to tell that the path starts at the root of the classpath. In case of classloader the path is assumed to be starting at the root of the classpath.

So the actual difference is the usage of [`Class#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) in one case and the [`ClassLoader#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) in the other.

In both cases, either do

```
//using classloader, path does not start with /
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/image.gif")
```

or do

```
//using class, path starts with /
getClass().getResource("/resources/image.gif")
```

Comment: I see. But what happens if I add a `/` while using ClassLoader?

Comment: That becomes an invalid path. But that's the default behavior as specified at [`ClassLoader#getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)), be careful because some custom classloader (e.g. in web container) the behavior is modified to handle both the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You check the resource to be not null in one ClassLoader and try to load from another ClassLoader (The may be different).

Answer (score 0):

in the first case you have

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/image.gif");
```

and in the second

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/image.gif")
```

is this difference causing the problem?